# SELECT all columns in addition to some summary columns using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Suppose there is a table with more than 20 columns: `(col1, col2, ... )`

If I want to display the sum of `col1` and `col2` as well as the other columns,
In SQL I could:

```
SELECT (col1+col2), * FROM table1;
```

But in LINQ, I have to

```
from tb in table1
select new
{
  sum = tb.col1 + tb.col2,
  col1 = tb.col1,
  col2 = tb.col2,
  ...
};
```

Is there another simpler ways? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq : select value in a datatable column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880163/linq-select-value-in-a-datatable-column)

Comment: Thanks but I am not filtering the results using where.
I am finding somethings like this in LINQ:
select new { sum = tb.col1 + tb.col2, tb.* }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend type of `tb` entity by `sum` property and write something like:

```
table1
    .Select(tb => new 
    {
        Tb = tb,
        Sum = tb.col1 + tb.col2
    })
    .Select(x =>
    {
        x.Tb.sum = x.Sum;
        return x.Tb;
    });
```