# Show projects on the basis of login user

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query which brings `Project Name` and `mkey`. The query is below

```
select  
    distinct
    comp.company_name as 'Company',EMP.emp_name as 'Employee',
     EMP.emp_card_no as 'Card_No',
     EMP.mkey as 'Mkey',
    isnull(hub.type_desc,'--NA--') as 'HUB_Name'
    ,isnull(Program_name,'--NA--') as 'Site',isnull(Project_name,'--NA--') as 'Project'
    from emp_mst EMP
    JOIN emp_mst1 PINFO ON EMP.MKEY=PINFO.MKEY 
    left join company_mst comp on EMP.comp_mkey=comp.mkey and fa_year=2008
    left join type_mst_a b1 on EMP.New_Dept_mkey=b1.master_mkey --and b1.type_code='d11'
    left join type_mst_a c1 on EMP.New_Subdept_mkey=c1.master_mkey-- and c1.type_code='d2'
    left join type_mst_a d1 on EMP.new_design_mkey=d1.master_mkey --and d1.type_code='dm1'
    left join type_mst_a e1 on EMP.ctc_hdr_mkey=e1.Add_IINFo1 and e1.type_code='gr'

    left join type_mst_a f1 on EMP.department_mkey=f1.master_mkey-- and f1.type_code='d1'
    left join type_mst_a g1 on EMP.designation_mkey=g1.master_mkey --and g1.type_code='dm'
    join emp_mst s1 on s1.mkey=EMP.reporting_to
    left join emp_mst s2 on s2.mkey=EMP.reporting_to2
    left join Emp_Address_Trl addr on addr.mkey=emp.mkey 
    left join state_mst as s on addr.state_mkey=s.mkey 
    left join city_mst as c on addr.city_mkey = c.mkey 
    left join view_p_program pg on EMP.project_mkey=pg.mkey 
    left join view_p_project pr on EMP.building_mkey=pr.mkey 
    left join type_mst_a hub on EMP.hub_mkey=hub.master_mkey and hub.type_code='HWH'
    WHERE 
    EMP.STATUS IN ('A','S')
```

SO what I want is, I want to show the `PROJECT NAME` of the assigned user on the form.

[image: PROJECT]

I want to show on `page_load` of the page.

```
<td align="right" class="Header" colspan="1">
            Location : <asp:label ID="lblproject" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%#= %>'></asp:label>
        </td>
```

how to bind the query so that it can show the relevant `project name`

Comment: Can't you pass logged-in user info to the query and add in Where clause Emp.ID or Emp.Card_No ?

Comment: @Sami: I know that, My issue is how to display it on the form ??

Comment: Ok, are you able to get query results in datatable/sqlReader/Class?

Comment: @Sami: yes, i can get that in `datatable` but in which control i will display it. for ex, `label`, `...`

Comment: GridView is good option to show query results .. I am posting my answer with code

Comment: i want to show just one username, why I will use gridview for that ??

Comment: Correct, posted an answer. might be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114592/discussion-between-n-k-and-sami).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code behind

```
var dtAsEnum= ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
string ProjectName= (from r in dtAsEnum
              where r.Field<string>("Employee") == 'LoggedInUser'
              select r.Field<string>("Project")).First<string>();

 Label.Text = ProjectName;
```

May be this helps or gives you an idea !

A ref. link: [Select Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880163/linq-select-value-in-a-datatable-column)